# WP search box on page not finding .PDF files

Tags: plugins, search, errors, links, code

Current marketing person left the business and I'm filling the role for now.

Receiving code from search page which formally was able to locate .PDF files by typing in and searching by key word(s.) The search box only pulls up general site map information now? No .PDFs or other files.

Code: [epkb-knowledge-base id=1]

A big thank you in advance!

Comment: You'll probably have to work out where the epkb-knowledge-base shortcode comes from (the ElementKit plugin?) and ask them for help - it's not something built into WordPress by default.

Comment: Thank you Rup! Have a great day.